# Android alertdialog set position and dimension top of a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I have a relative layout R and an alertdialog A. I want to set A's position and dimension same as R like this:

```
A.position_x = R.get_position_x()
A.position_y = R.get_position_y()
A.width = R.get_width()
A.height = R.get_height()
```

Comment: instead of position_x and position_y use left and top

Comment: you have got get param and set param use for that

Answer (score 2):

Use below code for set `AlertDialog` at top of screen:

```
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Title:");
                    builder.setMessage("Are you sure to Exit?");

                    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                          //Set ypu positive code on OK button
                           finish();
                        }
                    });
                    // Setting Negative "NO" Btn
                    builder.setNegativeButton("NO",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                    // Showing Alert Dialog
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
                    dialog.show();
```

Comment: Its not working because I want to set the dialog on top of a relative layout and also set its width and height same as the relative layout.

Comment: Ok , can you post your dialog code and xml code of relative layout in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Get height,width and position x and y of relativelayout from below code

```
rel1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rel1);

rel1.post(new Runnable() 
{

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        widthRel1 = rel1.getWidth();
        heightRel1 = rel1.getHeight();

        xRel1 = (int) rel1.getX();
        yRel1 = (int) rel1.getY();

    }
});
```

Then apply it to Dialog

```
final Dialog alertDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            alertDialog.setContentView(R.layout.template_menu);

            Window window = alertDialog.getWindow();
            WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();


              wlp.x = xRel1;   //x position        
              wlp.y = yRel1;   //y position

              wlp.height = heightRel1;  
           wlp.width = widthRel1;   

         wlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity. LEFT;


            window.setAttributes(wlp);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

            alertDialog.show();
```